# closed question - I don't think that working off a circuit schmatic and eagle's the same.

Tags: discussion, moderation, deleted-questions

I hope its the right place to ask, but i'd like to dispute the closing of one of my questions 
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/6735/from-schematic-to-perfboard-how-do-you-do-it-closed - its supposedly similar to another question, but i was referring to working from a paper drawing to protoboard - since i'm having a lot of trouble with it right now.

its far more general, and very likely to be more useful to the novice than the question its allegedly identical, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to keep it simple.

E&R is a community moderated site. The community clearly considers your question to be a duplicate. Now, as many have discussed before, some duplication is good. It helps with google results turning up our site. People in the field may have one specific name in mind, but the masses do not.

In general I try to only close duplicates that do not add to the google topics. You will see me close questions occasionally. Although your question does seem to be a different approach to the same question, the community did not think this difference was significant enough to warrant the second question.

I am sorry if you feel this was unfair, but the question is clearly a duplicate with a lightly different approach, and the community recognized this.

If you would like to have a discussion about this we can use chat at some point to discuss it.